# How to fix the position of LegendBox in the chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, legend, lineseries, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJS to create chart. Currently the position of legend box can be changed by dragging it. How can I fix the position of the legend box?
​

```
const legend = chart.addLegendBox()
.setOrigin(UIOrigins.RightTop)
.setPosition({ x: 90, y: 90 })
.setMargin({ left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10 })
legend.add(chart)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragging can be disabled with

```
legend.setDraggingMode( UIDraggingModes.notDraggable )
```